# Why behat keeps request headers between different scenarios?

Tags: behat, mink

A header (Authorizathion) I set in the one scenario still exists when second scenario is ran. 
I've looked through the documentation http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/ but I could find anything about my problem there. 
Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@insulated` feature tag, this will start a clean browser for each scenario.

If this is not the issue use a method in `@BeforeScenario` hook where you can call reset/restart session methods.